# what is the corresponding function of K.gradients for tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I want to visualize the classification result with tensorflow2.0. For keras, it need the following code for cam:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras.backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input, decodpredictions
import numpy as np
import cv2

img_path = 'image/test.jpg'

model = VGG16(weights='imagenet')
img = image.load_img('image/test.jpg', target_size=(224, 224))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = preprocess_input(x)
preds = model.predict(x)
print('Predicted:', decode_predictions(preds, top=3)[0])
print np.argmax(preds[0])
african_elephant_output = model.output[:, 386]
last_conv_layer = model.get_layer('block5_conv3')
grads = K.gradients(african_elephant_output, last_conv_layer.output)[0]
```

But when I use tensorflow2.0, it seem no such gradient function. So what is the  corresponding function for `K.gradients` for tensorflow2.0?

Comment: What actual error are you getting?

Comment: TypeError: gradients_v2() got an unexpected keyword argument 'colocate_gradients_with_ops'. @Matias Valdenegro

Comment: Are you using keras or tf.keras? because plain Keras is not compatible with Tensorflow 2.0 alpha/beta.

Comment: I am using keras.  but tf.keras get error too. I have updated my question and add more code.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
import keras.backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input, decodpredictions
```

You are mixing the `keras` and `tf.keras` packages, which are **NOT** compatible with each other. You should import backend from `tf.keras`:

```
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
```

Comment: It seems not work: 
`RuntimeError: tf.gradients is not supported when eager execution is enabled. Use tf.GradientTape instead.`

Comment: @tidy I would suggest not to use TensorFlow 2.0, because it is still a beta, there are still lots of bugs.

Comment: OK, thanks for you help @Matias Valdenegro. I'll try TensorFlow1.x.